# .htaccess - This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess

I'm cleaning my URLs and everything looks fine but whenever I try to access any directory such as images etc then chrome shows that "This webpage has a redirect loop." However I want to protect directories inside public_html.

The .htaccess file is inside public_html

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

I want to protect images, css and javascript directories but want to allow access to the admin directory.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change order of your rules and change your trailing slash removing rule:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# block all directories except admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !^admin(/|$) - [NC,F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Thanks it has now given me access to all the subdirectories of public_html. But I also want that the user will have access to the admin directory only but not the images, css and javascript.

Comment: So you want to block `http://domain.com/css/style.css` also OR just want to block `http://domain.com/css/`?

Comment: I i'm trying to access http://my-domain.com/images then it is listing all the images. I dont want this to happen. But there's a path http://my-domain.com/admin/ so that the admins of my site can access.

Comment: Thank a lot. What if I also want allow access to one more directory xyz too.

Comment: Just change block rule to: `RewriteRule !^(admin|xyz)(/|$) - [NC,F]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this remove all code and use this one
option index allow and disallow to be index directory like

This does the trick.

Options All -Indexes

## or

IndexIgnore *
for more information please check below link
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/htaccess-directory-listing-enable-disable-allow-deny-prevent-htaccess-directory-listing/

Comment: Thanks ohm that'r really nice and simple but Im handling images path differently.